# Como pasar parametros a una directiva desde un controlador? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

directive ('communicator',[ function(){
        return {
           template : (parametro);
        };

El parametro pasarlo desde un controlador

Comment: Amigo, edita tu pregunta que esta incompleta.

Comment: Digame que argumento falta especificar en mi pregunta? por favor.

Comment: Te recomendaría que le dieras una mirada a esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta porque esta incompleta pero buscando por internet encontre algo muy similar al paso de parametro por  directivas espero que te sirva ( es lo que entendio sobre tu problema si no es comenta o edita bien tu pregunta amigo )

[Link que encontre](https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/como-pasar-variables-como-atributos-en-directivas-de-angularjs/)